# Integer not changing when i call a setter method from another class

Tags: ios, class, integer, swift

I need to change an integer in one class from another. However every time that I try this it changes the variable momentarily which is strange. I have replicated the problem in this test application.

```
   import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

var theapples = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let battles = someclass(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90))
    self.view.addSubview(battles)

     let thetimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("apples"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func apples(){

++theapples
    println("\(theapples)")

}

func santa(){

theapples = 2
    println(" this is the number \(theapples)")

}
}
```

and heres my some class code

```
  import UIKit

  class someclass: UIView {

init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)

self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()




}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

let thepear = ViewController()
    thepear.santa()

self.removeFromSuperview()

}

 }
```

sorry to overwhelm with code but what this should do is every one second it should log a number that is one higher than the last. And when i tap my custom view it should set the integer theapples to 2 however it only does this temporarily. This is what the log looks like:

[image]

Comment: Is it asking too much that code in a question is formatted properly? The indention is horrible, and you did not even care to remove empty lines.

Comment: I'm sorry...I personally find this easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let thepear = ViewController()` creates a new (=different) instance of ViewController each time it is called